# Running .NET apps on Atom mobile device

Tags: .net, mobile, intel, managed-c++, intel-atom

I have a .NET WPF application using .NET 4.0.  It runs well on desktops and on laptops.  However, someone recently tried to install it on a 'mobile device' which has an Atom processor Z530, running Windows 7 32-bit Professional.  It appears to have the .NET 4.0 Client Profile and .NET 4.0 Extended installed.  However, our application fails to run on this device, and crashes on attempting to load a Managed C++ assembly.  Are there any special procedures that must be followed when building an application to target such a device?  Its specs are:

- Intel® Atom™ 1.6GHZ 512 KB L2 Cache
- 2GB DDR2 533 MHz
- DDR2 2GB DDR2 533MHz RAM
- Intel® GMA 500

Answer (score 2):

atom might not be a reason. Check if You have VC++ redistributable installed. Check if dll which cant be loaded is using libs ( dlls, .lib) that were built under a general path type like  ...\folder  rather than straight paths like  C:\something which doesnt exists on deployed machine